# How to export global load vector in abaqus

Tags: abaqus

In FEM, we needs to solve `K*u=P`, where `K` is global stiffness matrix, `u` is displacement, `P` is global load vector.

I want export global load vector, that is `P`.

I have a read at the manual, I add follow lines into the inp file.

```
*STEP
*MATRIX GENERATE, STIFFNESS, LOAD
*MATRIX OUTPUT, STIFFNESS, LOAD, FORMAT=MATRIX INPUT
*END STEP
```

After add the lines, then run the inp file, I can export the global stiffness matrix, I can see a "Job-1_STIF2.mtx" in the work directory, but there is nothing relate to global load vector. I do not know why the load vector can not be export.

Can anyone help me? Could you please modify my inp file? Or give any suggestions? Or give me an example inp that can export global load vector? Thanks for your time.

The full inp file shown as follow

```
*Heading
** Job name: Job-1 Model name: Job_my
** Generated by: Abaqus/CAE 2016
*Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO
**
** PARTS
**
*Part, name=PART-1
*Node
1, 0., 0., 0.
2, 0., 10., 0.
3, 10., 0., 0.
4, 10., 10., 0.
5, 0., 0., 5.
6, 0., 10., 5.
7, 10., 0., 5.
8, 10., 10., 5.
9, 0., 0., 10.
10, 0., 10., 10.
11, 10., 0., 10.
12, 10., 10., 10.
*Element, type=C3D4
1, 1, 3, 4, 8
2, 1, 3, 8, 5
3, 3, 8, 5, 7
4, 6, 5, 1, 8
5, 6, 1, 2, 4
6, 6, 1, 4, 8
7, 5, 7, 8, 12
8, 5, 7, 12, 9
9, 7, 12, 9, 11
10, 10, 9, 5, 12
11, 10, 5, 6, 8
12, 10, 5, 8, 12
*Elset, elset=Set-1, generate
1, 12, 1
** Section: Section-1
*Solid Section, elset=Set-1, material=MATERIAL-1
,
*End Part
**  
**
** ASSEMBLY
**
*Assembly, name=Assembly
**  
*Instance, name=PART-1-1, part=PART-1
*End Instance
**  
*Nset, nset=Set-1, instance=PART-1-1, generate
1, 4, 1
*Nset, nset=Set-2, instance=PART-1-1
1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10
*Nset, nset=Set-3, instance=PART-1-1, generate
1, 11, 2
*Elset, elset=_Surf-1_S2, internal, instance=PART-1-1
10,
*Elset, elset=_Surf-1_S3, internal, instance=PART-1-1
9,
*Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=Surf-1
_Surf-1_S2, S2
_Surf-1_S3, S3
*End Assembly
** 
** MATERIALS
** 
*Material, name=MATERIAL-1
*Elastic
100.,0.3
** 
** BOUNDARY CONDITIONS
** 
** Name: BC-1 Type: Displacement/Rotation
*Boundary
Set-1, 3, 3
** Name: BC-2 Type: Displacement/Rotation
*Boundary
Set-2, 1, 1
** Name: BC-3 Type: Displacement/Rotation
*Boundary
Set-3, 2, 2
** ----------------------------------------------------------------
** 
** STEP: Step-1
** 
*Step, name=Step-1, nlgeom=NO
*Static
1., 1., 1e-05, 1.
*Element Matrix Output,ELSET=PART-1-1.Set-1,
DLOAD=YES,File Name=element_matrix_vector,Frequency=1,Output File=User Defined,Stiffness=Yes,Mass=Yes

** 
** LOADS
** 
** Name: Load-1 Type: Pressure
*Dsload
Surf-1, P, 1.
** 
** OUTPUT REQUESTS
** 
*Restart, write, frequency=0
** 
** FIELD OUTPUT: F-Output-1
** 
*Output, field, variable=PRESELECT
** 
** HISTORY OUTPUT: H-Output-1
** 
*Output, history, variable=PRESELECT
*End Step

*STEP
*MATRIX GENERATE, STIFFNESS, LOAD
*MATRIX OUTPUT, STIFFNESS, LOAD, FORMAT=MATRIX INPUT
*END STEP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load should also be defined in the step which export the matrix.
That is, the line add to generate global system matrix should be:

```
*STEP
*MATRIX GENERATE,  STIFFNESS, LOAD
*MATRIX OUTPUT, STIFFNESS, LOAD, FORMAT=MATRIX INPUT
** 
** LOADS
** 
** Name: Load-1   Type: Pressure
*Dsload
Surf-1, P, 1.
*END STEP
```

full inp file shown as follows:

```
*Heading
** Job name: Job-1 Model name: Job_my
** Generated by: Abaqus/CAE 2016
*Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO
**
** PARTS
**
*Part, name=PART-1
*Node
      1,           0.,           0.,           0.
      2,           0.,          10.,           0.
      3,          10.,           0.,           0.
      4,          10.,          10.,           0.
      5,           0.,           0.,           5.
      6,           0.,          10.,           5.
      7,          10.,           0.,           5.
      8,          10.,          10.,           5.
      9,           0.,           0.,          10.
     10,           0.,          10.,          10.
     11,          10.,           0.,          10.
     12,          10.,          10.,          10.
*Element, type=C3D4
 1,  1,  3,  4,  8
 2,  1,  3,  8,  5
 3,  3,  8,  5,  7
 4,  6,  5,  1,  8
 5,  6,  1,  2,  4
 6,  6,  1,  4,  8
 7,  5,  7,  8, 12
 8,  5,  7, 12,  9
 9,  7, 12,  9, 11
10, 10,  9,  5, 12
11, 10,  5,  6,  8
12, 10,  5,  8, 12
*Elset, elset=Set-1, generate
  1,  12,   1
** Section: Section-1
*Solid Section, elset=Set-1, material=MATERIAL-1
,
*End Part
**  
**
** ASSEMBLY
**
*Assembly, name=Assembly
**  
*Instance, name=PART-1-1, part=PART-1
*End Instance
**  
*Nset, nset=Set-1, instance=PART-1-1, generate
 1,  4,  1
*Nset, nset=Set-2, instance=PART-1-1
  1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10
*Nset, nset=Set-3, instance=PART-1-1, generate
  1,  11,   2
*Elset, elset=_Surf-1_S2, internal, instance=PART-1-1
 10,
*Elset, elset=_Surf-1_S3, internal, instance=PART-1-1
 9,
*Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=Surf-1
_Surf-1_S2, S2
_Surf-1_S3, S3
*End Assembly
** 
** MATERIALS
** 
*Material, name=MATERIAL-1
*Elastic
100.,0.3
** 
** BOUNDARY CONDITIONS
** 
** Name: BC-1 Type: Displacement/Rotation
*Boundary
Set-1, 3, 3
** Name: BC-2 Type: Displacement/Rotation
*Boundary
Set-2, 1, 1
** Name: BC-3 Type: Displacement/Rotation
*Boundary
Set-3, 2, 2
** ----------------------------------------------------------------
** 
** STEP: Step-1
** 
*Step, name=Step-1, nlgeom=NO
*Static
1., 1., 1e-05, 1.
*Element Matrix Output,ELSET=PART-1-1.Set-1,
DLOAD=YES,File Name=element_matrix_vector,Frequency=1,Output File=User Defined,Stiffness=Yes,Mass=Yes

** 
** LOADS
** 
** Name: Load-1   Type: Pressure
*Dsload
Surf-1, P, 1.
** 
** OUTPUT REQUESTS
** 
*Restart, write, frequency=0
** 
** FIELD OUTPUT: F-Output-1
** 
*Output, field, variable=PRESELECT
** 
** HISTORY OUTPUT: H-Output-1
** 
*Output, history, variable=PRESELECT
*End Step

*STEP
*MATRIX GENERATE,  STIFFNESS, LOAD
*MATRIX OUTPUT, STIFFNESS, LOAD, FORMAT=MATRIX INPUT
** 
** LOADS
** 
** Name: Load-1   Type: Pressure
*Dsload
Surf-1, P, 1.
*END STEP
```